# Testing for three means in order

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test

Say I have data as follows: `type|value` where `type` takes values $A$, $B$ and $C$ and `value` is metric and numerical.

I know that testing $\mu_A<\mu_B$ can be done with a 2-sample t-test. Further I know that testing whether the means are different can be done with ANOVA.

But I want to test that $\mu_A<\mu_B<\mu_C$.

This [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/120427/20817) (which I asked) is similar and it mentions Fischer's Method where the Wikipedia page says:

> Fisher's method is a way of combining the information in the p-values from different statistical tests so as to form a single overall test:

which is what I want: to combine the p-value of $\mu_A<\mu_B$ with that of $\mu_B<\mu_C$. But the sentence continues...

> ...this method requires that the individual test statistics (or, more immediately, their resulting p-values) should be statistically independent.

which I suppose is not the case since the $\mu_B$ data are used in both tests.

So my question: How can I test the order of three means?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ANOVA with *post hoc* pairwise comparisons. Holm or Tukey correction on the p-value prevents against exceeding alpha level for the test.